# iPhone SDK During Authentication process, end up on blank permissions screen and fails

Tags: iphone, facebook, authentication, permissions

I have other apps using the Facebook SDK and authenticating properly.  Why this one is different, don't know.  Basically, during the authentication process:

```
  if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [facebook authorize:nil];
    }
```

It switches out to either the Facebook App or Safari, presents the login box, enter in USER/PWD it then redirects to the first screen.  Selecting OKAY, gets second screen.  The body of the screen is completely blank.

Is it a configuration problem with the app? Been stuck on this for a day now.

Cheers!

Ken

[image: Error received on iPhone, blank Permissions]

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the exact same issue and noticed that this happens systematically when the app you're trying to authorizing was already authorized before. Removing the app from Facebook's "App settings" fixes the issue. Clearly it's not a workaround since you can't ask the user to remove the app every time, but at least it allows you to go on with testing.

I'm still trying to figure out how to re-authorize without this blank page issue, but it really seems an issue on the Facebook side. Hope it gets fixed soon.

Tomas

Comment: Apparently there's a workaround: Open the advanced settings of your facebook app and set the Enhanced Auth Dialog to DISABLED.